# unable to set selected value on lightning:Select

Tags: lightningselect

I'm trying to set value for an lightning:select option. I have used Map to get value from Server and assigned to an map Attribute. Eventhough I'm setting the value to the attribute. It is not getting reflected in the page.

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static Map<String,String> loadOpportunityValues(Id OpportunityID){
    system.debug('OpportunityID+++++'+OpportunityID);
    Opportunity oppObj = [select id,product_division__c, SFI_ProductFamily__r.name, sfi_ProductGroup__r.name,
                         SFI_ProductHierarchy__r.name from Opportunity where id =: OpportunityId];
    Map<String,String>OppValuesMap = new Map<String,String>();
    if(oppObj.product_division__c!=null)
    OppValuesMap.put('ProductDivision',oppObj.product_division__c);
    if(oppObj.SFI_ProductFamily__r.name!=null)
    OppValuesMap.put('ProductFamily',oppObj.SFI_ProductFamily__r.name);
    if(oppObj.sfi_ProductGroup__r.name!=null)
    OppValuesMap.put('ProductGroup',oppObj.sfi_ProductGroup__r.name);
    if(oppObj.SFI_ProductHierarchy__r.name!=null)
    OppValuesMap.put('ProductHierarchy',oppObj.SFI_ProductHierarchy__r.name);

   return OppValuesMap;
}
```

and the lightning controller is

```
       if(recordID === "undefined"){
        alert('new Opportunity');
    }else{

        var action = component.get("c.loadOpportunityValues");
        action.setParams({ OpportunityID : recordID});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state+++'+state);
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.myMap",response.getReturnValue());
                var prodDiv = component.get("v.myMap.ProductDivision");  

                //component.find("selectedProductDivisionValue").set("v.value",prodDiv);
                component.set("v.selectedProductDivision","Amino Acids");  

                var prodFam = component.get("v.myMap.ProductFamily");

                component.set("v.selectedProductFamily",prodFam);   

                var prodGrp = component.get("v.myMap.ProductGroup");

                component.set("v.selectedProdGrp",prodGrp);

                var prodHierarchy = component.get("v.myMap.ProductHierarchy");

                component.set("v.selectedProdHierarchy",prodHierarchy);

            }
        }); 
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

and the lightning component is

```
<lightning:select aura:id="selectedProductDivisionValue"  value="{!v.selectedProductDivision}" onchange="{!c.getProductFamilies}" label="Product Division" required="true">
                        <aura:iteration var="option" items="{! v.ProdDivisionValues }">
                             <option value="{!option}">{!option}</option>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                    <lightning:select aura:id="selectedProdFamId"  value="{! v.selectedProductFamily }" onchange="{!c.getProductGroups}" label="Product Family" required="true">
                        <aura:iteration var="option" items="{! v.ProductFamilyValues }">
                             <option value="{!option}">{!option}</option>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                    <lightning:select aura:id="selectedProdGrpId" label="Product Group" value="{! v.selectedProdGrp }" onchange="{!c.getProductHierarchies}" required="false">
                        <aura:iteration var="option" items="{! v.prodGrpValues }">
                              <option value="{!option}">{!option}</option>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                    <lightning:select aura:id="selectedProdHierarchyId" value="{! v.selectedProdHierarchy }" label="Product Hierarchy" required="false">
                        <aura:iteration var="option" items="{! v.prodHierarchyValues }">
                            <option value="{!option}">{!option}</option>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lightning is cAsE sEnSiTiVe. Please check the capitalization of the field names. I can guarantee at least some of them are wrong, as "name" should be "Name".